# Sequence of monotone tuples and permutation condition for rotation

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics, symmetric-groups, catalan-numbers

I was doing some counting in $S_n$ symmetric group I encountered the following problem, which also someway related to central factorial number.
So given a $n$ cycle say $(1,2,\ldots,n)$, what are the monotonic 2 -tuples, of the form $(a,b)(c,d)$, monotonicity in on the 2nd coordinate that is $b<d$ such that. By default transposition $(a,b)$ imply $a<b$.

$$(1,2,\ldots,n)(a,b)(c,d)=\, \text{is still a $n$ cycle } $$
I have succesfully answer the question that is that is having chosen $a,b ,d$, $c\in [a,b)$ that is c can take the value $a$ and all the integer between $a$ and $b$ not $b$.

Let me give you an example say, let's take the 3 cycles $(1,2,3)$ then
say you give me $(1,3)(c,3)$ then $ 1\leq c <3$ are the tuples that multiply with $(1,2,3)$ gives back 3 cycle. For this case there are only two other choice
$(1,2)(1,3)$ and $(1,2)(1,2)$.
This work for all $n$ cycle. Now question start from here.
Say I am given an arbitrary $n$ cycle say what would the above classification look like? I still want my cycle to be monotonic in 2 nds coordinate. Let me give some examples to make my problem explicit.

Say I have been given a 4 cycle $(1,4,2,3)$. Now I want to find all the tuples $\{(a,b)(c,d)\mid b\leq d\}$  such that it multiplies to give back the 4 cycles.

To start with we have $( 1,4 )(c,4)$ what should the condition we put on $c$? The cycle $(1,4)(2,4)$ is not answer as it multiply to give a cycle of type $(2,1,1)$.

The natural thing that comes to my mind is there is something to do with the order of the integer. In the first natural cycle, we have the natural order
$1 < 2 < 3 < 4$.

For the cycle in example say we attempt to put an order
$1<4<2<3 $
these order only for the first coordinates to give conditions for monotonic tuples to give back $n$ cycles. With this order in mind, I can create the following tuples
$(2,4)(3,4)$ which when multiplied give back 4 cycles. This also explains why $(1,4)(2,4)$ is not an example as in the above order 2 is greater than 4 hence it's not an answer. Is this can be generalised? Or I am doing something that can be explained nicer more mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED.** If we represent a given cycle as a circle with $n$ vertices, and transpositions $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ and $(c,d)$ with $c<d$ as chords in this circle, then their product is a cycle if and only if

- the chords cross; or
- coincide, i.e. $(a,b)=(c,d)$; or
- one of $c,d$ equals $a$ and the other is clockwise strictly in between $b$ and $a$; or
- one of $c,d$ equals $b$ and the other is clockwise strictly in between $a$ and $b$.

---

**Example.** A cycle $(1,8,4,7,2,5,3,6)$ and $(a,b)=(4,6)$ have graphical representation:

[image]

Then for $(c,d)$ with $d\geq b=6$ we have the following options:

- $c\in\{1,6\}$ and $d=7$;
- $c\in\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $d\in\{6,8\}$;
- $c=7$ and $d=8$.

**ADDED.** It can be shown that independently of a given cycle of length $n$ the total number of pairs of transpositions $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ with $a<b$, $c<d$, and $b\leq d$ equals $\binom{n+2}{4}$.

Comment: I didn't get it, so the tuples must me $(a ,b)(c,d)$ where $b\leq d$ it's always $a<b$ and $c<d$ as in transposition. I gave the condition on $c$ so I guess you want to say something about $\pi_c$?

Comment: As I want monotonic sequence $b,d$ are fixed like $(a,2)(c,3)$ or $(a,2)(c,2)$ so on, we cannot change the position $b,d$

Comment: In the case of 4 cycles all possible things are $(a,4)(c,4)$, $(a,3)(c,4)$, $(a,2)(c,4)$, $(a,3)(c,3)$, $(a,2)(c,3)$ and we need to fill in condition of $a,c$

Comment: A transposition in a symmetric group given by $(a,b)$ always implied $a<b$. Maybe I should add it, as I thought it's universal. Yes $a< b \leq d$ also $c<d$ hold by default.

Comment: @GGT: Transposition is a special case of a cycle, and as such it does not assume any order within (...) by default. So, requirement $a<b$ needs to be stated explicitly. It is still not clear though whether you want $b<d$ or $b\leq d$ as you have both in your question.

Comment: I see, I have edited it now. Thanks a lot

Comment: $b\leq d$ as I want to include the trivial tuples like $(1,3)(1,3)$ in my counting.

Comment: if we take =3, then =[2,4,1,3], implying that =4 and {,}={1,2}; this one should not be in my list as it's not monotonic in 2nd variable though it preserves 4 cycles.

Comment: As the tuple is $(3,4)(1,2) $ not monotonic

Comment: @GGT: I've updated the answer.

Comment: "one of , equals  and the other is clockwise strictly in between  and " as monotonicity $b\leq d$ and $a<b$ so d cannot equal a.

Comment: These are additional restrictions - you may add them as many as you like. The statement is just about when the product is a cycle (without any other restrictions).

Comment: I see yes, so the condition that I have described for the cycle $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ will translate to any $n$ cycle by your representation of in diagram form.

Comment: Btw, it is possible to enumerate all pairs of transpositions satisfying $a<b$, $c<d$ and $b\leq d$.

Comment: For the case $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ I can enumerate and the number is the central factorial number $T(n+1,n)$. But I haven't counted when it's other $n$ cycle.

Comment: Given a Chord diagram with two chords is there uniquely given be a tuple that preserves the cycle? I feel I have to given an ordering tot the chord

Comment: For example, if we have $(1,2,3,4)$ and we have two tuples $(1,4) (3,4)$ now we need to mention which chord in the sequence should come first to be an tuple we look for?

Comment: I've added the count to the answer. It's always $\binom{n+2}4$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Given a chord diagram can we write the tuple (a,b)(c,d) such that it multiplies to give a cycle?  Do we need to put some ordering or orientation?

Comment: E.g., for two crossing chords: $d$ is the maximum of the four chord ends, $c$ is the opposite chord end to $d$, $b$ and $a$ are the largest and smallest among the other two chord ends.

Comment: Hi Max, I posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428503/non-crossing-and-crossing-bijection-in-higher-genus

Comment: If you have any answer to this please let me know